# How to run a unitest testsuite from parent directory

Tags: python, python-unittest, test-suite

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── runner.py
    └── test_foo.py
```

Where the test files look like this:

**test_foo.py**

```
import unittest
from ..src.foo import *

class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            pass
        
        def test_foo(self):
            foo = Foo()
            res = foo.get_something('bar')
        
            if res is None:
                self.fail('something bad happened')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(self)
```

**runner.py**

```
import unittest

# import test modules
import test_foo

# initialize the test suite
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite  = unittest.TestSuite()

# add tests to the test suite
suite.addTests(loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_foo))

# initialize a runner, pass it your suite and run it
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3)
result = runner.run(suite)
```

I would like to run all of my tests from the parent directory in a testsuite so I attempt to call unites like this:

```
python -m test/runner.py
```

But it complains with the following:

```
$ python -m test/runner.py 
/usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.
```

if I move to the test directory, I get a different error:

```
$ python -m runner
  File "test_foo.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..src.foo import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I would like to keep all test related stuff in the parent/test directory if possible.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I would highly recommend using `pytest` over `unittest`

Comment: Why would you recommend pytest over unitest?

Comment: Try to run with ```python -m test.runner```

Comment: I’m away from my code at the moment but I believe I tried that and it complained about not finding a module called ‘runner’

Answer (score 0):

try `python -m unittest test.runner`.  Here's the structure I used.

```
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo.py
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_foo.py
    └── runner.py
```

my `foo.py` contains a simple function, `foo`. I changed the import statement in the `test_foo.py` to the following:

`from src.foo import foo`.

I also ran directly from `runner.py` with the following changes.

`from test import test_foo`

and then in the command line at the parent directory, `python -m unittest test.runner`

This structure only works from the parent directory. If I try it in the test directory, it fails to import.

Comment: I don't want to use the discover method because I want to explicitly add tests to my suite. I tried calling `python -m unittest test/runner.py` but got some errors again: `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`

Comment: what python version?  if 2, try `from __future__ import absolute_import`.

Comment: I tried with 2 and 3. Surely I don't need to import additional libs just to run unites with a standard directory structure?

Comment: I get this with python3: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.runner'`

Comment: all i can say is that, "well it works on my computer"  :( . in py2.7 and 3.5.  and now i really want to know why it doesn't on yours.